# Why is this KStream/KTable topology propagating records that don't pass the filter?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have the following topology that:

1. Creates a state store
2. Filters records based on SOME_CONDITION, maps its values to a new entity and finally publishes these records to another topic STATIONS_LOW_CAPACITY_TOPIC

However I am seeing this on the STATIONS_LOW_CAPACITY_TOPIC:

```
�   null
�   null
�   null
�   {"id":140,"latitude":"40.4592351","longitude":"-3.6915330",...}
�   {"id":137,"latitude":"40.4591366","longitude":"-3.6894151",...}
�   null
```

That is to say, it's as if it were also publishing to the STATIONS_LOW_CAPACITY_TOPIC topic those records that didn't pass the filter. How is this possible? How can I prevent them to be published?

This is the ksteams code:

```
kStream.groupByKey().reduce({ _, newValue -> newValue },
                Materialized.`as`<Int, Station, KeyValueStore<Bytes, ByteArray>>(STATIONS_STORE)
                        .withKeySerde(Serdes.Integer())
                        .withValueSerde(stationSerde))
                .filter { _, value -> SOME_CONDITION }
                .mapValues { station ->
                    Stats(XXX)
                }
                .toStream().to(STATIONS_LOW_CAPACITY_TOPIC, Produced.with(Serdes.Integer(), stationStatsSerde))
```

**UPDATE:** I've simplyfied to topology and printed the resulting table. For some reason the final KTable also contains null valued records corresponding to upstream records that didn't pass the filter:

```
kStream.groupByKey().reduce({ _, newValue -> newValue },
                Materialized.`as`<Int, BiciMadStation, KeyValueStore<Bytes, ByteArray>>(STATIONS_STORE)
                        .withKeySerde(Serdes.Integer())
                        .withValueSerde(stationSerde))
                .filter { _, value ->
                    val conditionResult = (SOME_CONDITION)
                    println(conditionResult)
                    conditionResult
                }
                .print()
```

**Logs:**

```
false
[KTABLE-FILTER-0000000002]: 1, (null<-null)
false
[KTABLE-FILTER-0000000002]: 2, (null<-null)
false
[KTABLE-FILTER-0000000002]: 3, (null<-null)
false
[KTABLE-FILTER-0000000002]: 4, (null<-null)
true
[KTABLE-FILTER-0000000002]: 5, (Station(id=5, latitude=40.4285524, longitude=-3.7025875, ...)<-null)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer was in the javadoc of `KTable.filter(...)`:

> Note that filter for a changelog stream works different to record
>   stream filters, because records with null values (so-called tombstone
>   records) have delete semantics. Thus, for tombstones the provided
>   filter predicate is not evaluated but the tombstone record is
>   forwarded directly if required (i.e., if there is anything to be
>   deleted). Furthermore, for each record that gets dropped (i.e., dot
>   not satisfy the given predicate) a tombstone record is forwarded.

That explains why I'm seeing null valued (tombstone) records sent downstream.

To avoid it I converted the KTable to KStream and then applied the filter:

```
kStream.groupByKey().reduce({ _, newValue -> newValue },
                Materialized.`as`<Int, Stations, KeyValueStore<Bytes, ByteArray>>(STATIONS_STORE)
                        .withKeySerde(Serdes.Integer())
                        .withValueSerde(stationSerde))
                .toStream()
                .filter { _, value -> SOME_CONDITION }
                .mapValues { station ->
                    StationStats(station.id, station.latitude, station.longitude, ...)
                }
                .to(STATIONS_LOW_CAPACITY_TOPIC, Produced.with(Serdes.Integer(), stationStatsSerde))
```

**Result:**

```
4   {"id":4,"latitude":"40.4302937","longitude":"-3.7069171",...}
5   {"id":5,"latitude":"40.4285524","longitude":"-3.7025875",...}
...
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped!